# Unable to send Kafka Message through port forwarding

Tags: centos, apache-kafka, portforwarding, kafka-producer-api

I have an issue about sending message to Kafka using port forwarding. We are using port forwarding for Kafka like this:

```
| Hostname | IP            | Port | Port Forwarding       |
|----------|---------------|------|-----------------------|
| kafka01  | 192.168.0.100 | 9092 | 106.107.118.119:30124 |
| kafka02  | 192.168.0.101 | 9092 | 106.107.118.119:30125 |
| kafka03  | 192.168.0.102 | 9092 | 106.107.118.119:30126 |
```

To connect to kafka broker from my localhost, I have to use VPN to connect to these addresses `192.168.0.X:9092` and it sent message to Kafka from my localhost (my laptop) successfully. But when deploying my application to real servers which has to use port forwarding to connect to Kafka brokers, it sent no message to kafka without any error display.

From real servers, it still can connect to kafka brokers (`telnet 106.107.118.119 30124` successfully). I have no idea why. This is the producer config:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 | [2017-07-29 04:34:36]  INFO - 
ProducerConfig values: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   compression.type = none
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   metric.reporters = []
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   metadata.fetch.timeout.ms =         
60000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   acks = 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   batch.size = 16384
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   reconnect.backoff.ms = 10
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   bootstrap.servers = 
[106.107.118.119:30124, 106.107.118.119:30125, 106.107.118.119:30126]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   retry.backoff.ms = 100
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   buffer.memory = 33554432
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   timeout.ms = 30000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   key.serializer = class 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   retries = 0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   max.request.size = 1048576
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   block.on.buffer.full = true
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   value.serializer = class 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   send.buffer.bytes = 131072
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   metrics.num.samples = 2
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   linger.ms = 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |   client.id = 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/07/29 16:34:36 |  - in logAll() at line 113 of 
class org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig
```

It does not show any error but when using simple Kafka consumer application, there is no message in kafka, while it has message when sending from my computer (`bootstrap.servers=[192.168.0.100:9092, 192.168.0.101:9092, 192.168.0.102:9092]`). Any one knows about this issue?

Comment: How did you set up your listeners? Can you post relevant sections of your `server.properties`? After initial connection Kafka will advertise its endpoints to the clients based on the config.

Comment: `advertised.listeners` (see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) should be set to the addresses your "real servers" can see (eg. `106.107.118.119:30124`), is that the case?

Comment: I tried to set advertised.listeners to 106.107.118.119:30124 but it still cannot send messages. The log shows: "The configuration 'advertised.listeners' was supplied but isn't a known config", I tried both kafka 0.8 and 0.10 this issue is still there.

Comment: Can you post your `server.properties` @keduadoi to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or somewhere else?