# How to reach Kafka on private network from outside?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a server with Zookeeper and Kafka in private network on `10.242.44.55`. I have forwarded port on gateway from `[public_ip]:39092` to `10.242.44.55:9092`. I took the following settings for Kafka from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930068/how-to-produce-messages-from-public-computers-to-a-kafka-installation-on-a-priva):

```
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:39092
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://10.242.44.55:9092,EXTERNAL://[public_ip]:39092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Everything works fine in private network. I can produce and consume messages from different computers. Unfortunatelly when I tried to produce a message from outside I got an error:

```
pers@pc:/opt/kafka$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh —broker-list [public_ip]:39092 —topic test
>testMessage
>[2018-03-24 17:51:04,393] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 11 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-1: 1505 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
[2018-03-24 17:53:13,970] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

The same time I can reach this socket with telnet:

```
pers@pc:/opt/kafka$ telnet [public_ip] 39092
Trying [public_ip]...
Connected to [public_ip].
Escape character is '^]'.
test
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

[I saw that another man had such problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386875/unable-to-send-kafka-message-through-port-forwarding), but there are no solutions.
 Anybody knows what I'm doing worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally solved my problem. Kafka works fine when the same ports are used in ports forwarding.

This is part of my broker's config:

```
listeners=EXTERNAL://:39092,INTERNAL://:9092
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://77.1.1.1:39092,INTERNAL://10.1.1.1:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Comment: @v-perfilev:What do you mean by `Kafka works fine when the same ports are used in ports forwarding.`  I don't see the difference between your solution config and your problem config.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working port forwarding simple config of kafka.
port 19082 should be open on external ip**

```
    broker.id=0
    advertised.host.name=192.168.129.36
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
    advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://122.112.92.146:19092
```